# How many integer points are contained within a cube's intersection with plane?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Consider the integral points (x, y, z)(x,y,z) on the plane $35 x + 55 y + 77 z = 1$. How many are contained within a cube with side length 30 centered at (0, 0, 0)?

https://brilliant.org/problems/points-in-a-box-2/#!/solution-comments/

The solution by the author is not very comprehensive. I understand it vaguely until the end where the author ends with "part two: solving inequalities". How would you go about turning this into an inequality?

Thanks to everyone answering (-:

(Extension: Would it be possible to do this with a 3D space and 4D hypercube? Just wondering.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

You have the system

$$35x + 55y + 77z = 1$$

$$-15 \leq x,y,z \leq 15$$

Let $x+15 = X, y+15=Y, z+15 = Z$

The system becomes

$$35X + 55Y + 77Z = 2506$$

$$0 \leq X,Y,Z \leq 30$$

Can you solve it now? It's a basic combinatorial problem you can solve using stars and bars method